# Tensor product and quiver

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products, quiver

I have studied the course representation theory about Category module (module over finite dimensional algebra).

A module over finite dimensional algebra can be seen as a reprensatation of a quiver.

I don't know whether tensor product of two modules (over finite dimensional algebra) can be seen as a reprensatation of a quiver?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $k$-algebras (where $k$ is a commutative ring), then the general rule for tensor products if the following: for an $A$-$B$-bimodule $_A M_B$ and a $B$-$C$-bimodule $_BN_C$, the tensor product $M\otimes_B N$ is an $A$-$C$-bimodule.

Let's apply this to your situation.  You have a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra, say $\Lambda$.  You have two modules over $\Lambda$.  Let's say they are left modules $_\Lambda M$ and $_\Lambda N$.  Since none of them is a *right* $\Lambda$-module, we cannot take their tensor product over $\Lambda$.  The only reasonable choice is to take their tensor product over $k$.

To do this, note that $M$ has a natural structure of right $k$-module, and that $N$ has a structure of left $k$-module.  Thus $M\otimes_k N$ is defined.  According to the above, it is a left $\Lambda$-module; however, it is not so interesting, since it is isomorphic to a direct sum of a number of copies of $M$ equal to the $k$-dimension of $N$.